# Directory access in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory

I use the .htaccess file in 'Logs' folder for logs files.

This is the .htaccess code:

> order deny, allow
>
> deny from all

But I want to do that from the main .htaccess, That found near to index.php and other files

How can I do this?

Comment: Don't use .htaccess to prevent access to "secret" files. Put those files OUTSIDE of your document root so they're not accessible, period.

Comment: @Almog: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not put your 'secret' files below your public directory. It's a unnecessary safety risk! BUT, if somehow you find yourself in a position that you might feel obligate to do so you'll have to put the `.htaccess` in the directory itself (The one you're trying to block).

See, htaccess files are for [distributed configuration of directories](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-1828/gdeun/index.html), so it only refers to the current directory. But I still strongly recomend that you put your logs directories outside the web root. :D